# Paypal express checkout integration with PayPal REST API

Tags: php, curl, paypal, express-checkout

I'm trying to integrate Paypal express checkout integration with PayPal REST API.

JS file looks like this:

```
paypal.Button.render({
    env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
    commit: true,
    payment: function() {
        var CREATE_URL = 'createpayment';

        return paypal.request.get(CREATE_URL)
            .then(function(res) {
                return res.paymentID;
            });
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        var EXECUTE_URL = 'executepayment';
        var data = {
            paymentID: data.paymentID,
            payerID: data.payerID
        };
        return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_URL, data)
            .then(function (res) {
                window.alert('Payment Complete!');
            });
    }

}, '#paypal-button-container');
```

Now I can't figure out what should be in CREATE_URL and EXECUTE_URL url's php files. I have read a lot of their docs. I understand that in php I should make first request to get token, then I should make create-payment request and after execute-payment curl reuqest. But I have no-luck.

I also don't understand how should I pass payment value to CREATE_URL php file.

Several days ago I found here some good answer of my question with all examples, but it's about two days I can't find it.

**Update**: ALso I need to pass input amount to php file from payment request. And I can't do that using return paypal.request.get(CREATE_URL, data)
 request.

Can anybody help me please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Share some examples for server PHP code.

PHP Code in CREATE_URL:

```html
    <?php
    $curl = curl_init();
     
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
        'USER' => 'xxxxx',
        'PWD' => 'xxxxx',
        'SIGNATURE' => 'xxxxx',
     
        'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
        'VERSION' => '108',
        'LOCALECODE' => 'en_US',
     
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => 100,
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => 100,
     
        'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => 'test name',
        'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => 'test desc',
        'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => 1,
        'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => 100,
     
        'CANCELURL' => 'http://localhost/cancel.html',
        'RETURNURL' => 'http://localhost/success.html'
    )));
     
    $response =    curl_exec($curl);
     
    curl_close($curl);
     
    $nvp = array();
     
    if (preg_match_all('/(?<name>[^\=]+)\=(?<value>[^&]+)&?/', $response, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches['name'] as $offset => $name) {
            $nvp[$name] = urldecode($matches['value'][$offset]);
        }
    }
    if (isset($nvp['ACK']) && $nvp['ACK'] == 'Success') {
        echo $nvp['TOKEN'];
    } else {
        //failed
    } 

    ?>
```

PHP Code in EXECUTE_URL:

```html
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
    'USER' => 'xxxxx',
    'PWD' => 'xxxxx',
    'SIGNATURE' => 'xxxxx',
 
    'METHOD' => 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment',
    'VERSION' => '108',
    'LOCALECODE' => 'en_US',
 
    'TOKEN' => $_POST['TOKEN'],
    'PayerID' => $_POST['PAYERID'],
 
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => 100,
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => 100,
     
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => 'test name',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => 'test desc',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => 100,
)));
 
$response =    curl_exec($curl);
 
curl_close($curl);
 
$nvp = array();
 
if (preg_match_all('/(?<name>[^\=]+)\=(?<value>[^&]+)&?/', $response, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches['name'] as $offset => $name) {
        $nvp[$name] = urldecode($matches['value'][$offset]);
    }
}
 
print_r($nvp);
```